# Tableau integration in Angular not working

Tags: angular, api, tableau-api

I am trying to add the Tableau in my angular app. I followed the steps but for some reason i can't see the table in my div.

my code is

```
declare var tableau: any;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tableau',
  templateUrl: './tableau.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tableau.component.scss']
})
export class TableauComponent implements OnInit {
  viz: any;
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  initTableau() {
    const containerDiv = document.getElementById("vizContainer");
    const vizUrl =
        "https://public.tableau.com/views/VacationHome/VacationHome?:embed=y&:display_count=yes";

        const options = {  
          hideTabs: true,  
          onFirstInteractive: () => {  
              console.log("onFirstInteractive");  
          },   
          // onFirstVizSizeKnown: () => {  
          //     console.log("onFirstVizSizeKnown");   
          // }  
      };  

    this.viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, vizUrl, options);

}
HTML : <div id="vizContainer" style="width:800px; height:800px; display: flex; justify-content: right; border: 2px solid black;"></div>
```

I donot see any errors in the terminal/console. I can see the empty div. What possibly am I missing?

Comment: From where are you running `initTableau()`?

Comment: Sorry thats a silly mistake, guess I'm still very new to code. But thanks @R.Richards

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by [R. Richards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5437671/r-richards), you haven't really called `initTableau` anywhere in your Component. That would be required to initialize Tableau.

Also, instead of using `document.getElementById`, use `@ViewChild`

You should then call the `initTableau` method in `ngAfterViewInit`.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";

declare var tableau: any;

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  viz: any;
  @ViewChild("vizContainer") containerDiv: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initTableau();
  }

  initTableau() {
    // const containerDiv = document.getElementById("vizContainer");
    const vizUrl =
      "https://public.tableau.com/views/VacationHome/VacationHome?:embed=y&:display_count=yes";

    const options = {
      hideTabs: true,
      onFirstInteractive: () => {
        console.log("onFirstInteractive");
      },
      onFirstVizSizeKnown: () => {
        console.log("onFirstVizSizeKnown");
      }
    };
    this.viz = new tableau.Viz(
      this.containerDiv.nativeElement,
      vizUrl,
      options
    );
  }
}
```

And in your Template:

```
<div
  #vizContainer
  style="display: flex; justify-content: center"
></div>
```

**NOTE:** Make sure that you're including the tableau script in your index.html

```
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"
></script>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/tableau-example-d7xkd) for your ref.

Comment: thanks @SiddAjmera - works like charm - I am still very new to Angular learning. Question though, what is the difference between using ViewChild and dom manipulation directly. and when is the best practice to use either of these.

Comment: [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/6pip2x/why_use_viewchild/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share) should answer your question. 

Comment: Nice answer @SiddAjmera! Thanks for the props.

Comment: thanks a bunch @SiddAjmera it is indeed explained answer and I'm quiet clear now.

Comment: Perfect! Please consider marking this answer as a solution to close the loop. Cheers!

Comment: I'am afraid I don't know how to do that. I cannot vote up your solution either because of less reputation. @SiddAjmera

Comment: @SiddAjmera , How to use viz.dispose() function to remove the viz? I am getting

 "another viz is already present in element"

Please help with this.

Comment: @ADARSHK, I'd suggest creating a new thread to keep this thread focused on a single problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for another ways of embedding a Tableau report using the JavaScript API, I want to add two options:

- The unofficial library [ngx-tableau](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-tableau) provides a simple interface
  to the Tableau JavaScript API v2, offering multiple configuration
  options.
- The official [Tableau Embedding API v3](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/embedding_api/en-us/index.html) exposes a web-component
  with a very similar API and some other features.